# Vim: run one filetype's processing when opening another filetype

Tags: vim, plugins, startup, file-type

I'll be editing some .less files.  Now, I want the filetype to be "less", but I want vim to do all inclusions of css and css3 plugins when opening a .less file.

There are times I'd like to be able to do this that may be less obvious as well, but if we can figure out the best method for this particular case, I can modify the technique for what I need.

Thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To "inherit" filetype settings from another filetype, use this as a starting point; you can add customizations after it. Place it at `~/.vim/ftplugin/less.vim`:

```
if exists('b:did_ftplugin') | finish | endif

runtime! ftplugin/css.vim
runtime! ftplugin/css_*.vim ftplugin/css/*.vim
```

Comment: Is that second one basically two calls to runtime!  ?

Comment: Apparently, by the time the script is called, the b:did_ftplugin does in fact exist...

Comment: There are three different file patterns for filetype plugins. The split into two `:runtime` commands ensures that the main one gets sourced first, but you could also put all three patterns after one `:runtime`.

Comment: Thank you, once  again, Ingo.  You are ever helpful.  :-)